# What is the name of a sci-fi movie where an alien vehicle collects sample of living beings on different planets?

Tags: story-identification, aliens

Name of a sci-fi movie where an alien vehicle collects sample of living beings on different planets. When it comes to Earth a boy becomes its friend. I don't remember much of the movie but one scene is that earthlings get a hold of the vehicle and keeps it in captive using big chains and heavy weights. Vehicle is silver in color and almond shaped.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Disney's [Flight of the Navigator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_of_the_Navigator)

> Inside he meets its pilot, an artificial intelligence called a
>   Trimaxian Drone Ship, whom David nicknames Max...
>
> ...Max tells David that his mission was to travel the galaxy, collect
>   biological specimens, take them to Phaelon for analysis and then
>   return them to their homes.

[image]

**[Picture Source](http://www.imdb.com/media/rm1848937984/tt0091059?ref_=ttmi_mi_all_sf_2)**

Comment: Man, I love this movie.